# Не доходят POST запросы с платёжных систем

Tags: post, php

Переехал на новый хостинг, перестали доходить пост запросы от платёжных систем ЯД и КИВИ.

```
url типа http://site.ru/post.php
```

Открываю руками - всё работает, делаю тест на яндексе - пишет Ошибка! Этот адрес недоступен. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: @Rammsteinik, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Когда я начинал разработку, столкнулся с подобными ошибками при 301 редиректе с `site.ru/test` на `site.ru/test/`. При редиректе на / - POST данные теряются. Может с этим связано?

Comment: нет, тут вид типа http://site.ru/post.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ошибка в исходном запросе на Яндексе
2. Блокировка Яндекса вашим сервером.

Comment: 1. Нет. На другом сервере работает этот же код.
2. Так же блокируется вм и киви.

Comment: Блокировала антиддос защита